# Querying Django ORM inside celery task: SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async

Tags: python, django, celery, django-orm, gevent

We're using celery jobs alongside Django and within different celery tasks there are several occasions where the celery task is reading and writing to the database through Django's ORM.

Every once in a while when using the ORM inside the celery task, the tasks throws:

**SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.**

I find it strange that it happens sometimes, rather than every time a query is made through the ORM? Secondly, when trying to resolve it as per the suggestions in the Django documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/

like so: [Example of sync_to_asynch ussage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhptN.png)

I run into another problem:
**TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not iterable**

My questions are:

1. Why does this issue only occur every once in a while and not every time I query using the ORM inside the celery task?
2. Is there a way it can be solved?

**Environment**

The celery tasks are run with gevent like so:
celery -A Tasks  worker -P gevent -c 10 -l INFO -E

Python 3.8

Django 3.1.4

Celery 5.1.0

Comment: Make sure that you don't pass objects like models trough args if you need to pass data related to database just pass the `pk` and then in the function make the query 'cause celery doesn't work ok with ORM objects passed as parameters.

Comment: Thanks! That's handled already though and is not the problem in this case.

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in your question as well as the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

`sync_to_async()` will return a coroutine. As the TypeError hints at, you can't iterate over a coroutine directly. You must `await` it, as shown in the example.

From the docs:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

results = await sync_to_async(Blog.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(pk=123)
```

In your picture, you do not `await` the call.

Comment: Thank you! That's absolutely right. The next problem I run into if I await ithe call is that it requires the function declaration to be async. The problem I think then is that Celery gevent is spawning green threads (since I use gevent) and it's not really a async context that can be declared with the async keyword since celery is taking care of this thread asynchronous green thread spawning. Is there any way around that or do I have to resort to use prefork rather than gevent in my celery settings?